# not able to read Hindi font in genrated pdf using jspdf in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-hooks, jspdf

i want to display hindi font in genrated pdf using jspdf and reactjs. in genrated code hindi font is shows like œ
Ë
¤
®
Ç
¤
®
¾
°
Á
‚
Ÿ
Ë
•
¨
—
Á
®
¾
µ
›
Ë.

¤
®
¾
°
Ç
¨
µ
Á
‚
Ÿ
Ë
•
¨
®
Ç
³
µ
µ
¾
¨
À

œ
°
Â
°
›
Ç

import HindiFont from "../assets/font/hindi.ttf";

```
       const pdf = new jsPDF("portrait", "px", [100, 120]);
                pdf.addFileToVFS('HindiFont.ttf', HindiFont);
                pdf.addFont('HindiFont.ttf', 'HindiFont', 'normal');
            
                // Set the font for the text you want to write
                pdf.setFont('HindiFont');
                pdf.html(ref.current, {
                  margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  html2canvas: {
                    scale: 0.6,
                  },
                  callback: (pdf) => {
                    pdf.autoPrint();
                    pdf.output("dataurlnewwindow");
                  },
                });
```